# pushwoosh register and unregister

Tags: android, push-notification, android-lifecycle, pushwoosh

i have using the code as explained in the pushwoosh site .

they ask for this in the activity life cycle :

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    //Re-register receivers on resume
    registerReceivers();
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    //Unregister receivers on pause
    unregisterReceivers();
}
```

something is very not clear to me and it is drive me crazy , this is a push service why do we need to unregister each time activity is paused ?

and why do we need so much code in my mainActivity instead of few lines in my application class ?

i didn't chose this library but i gut to understand what the logic of that...i don't remember in other push services so much code and need to unRegister .

home i asked my question right because i really want to understand .

this is the full code for main activity

http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/native-android-sdk

Comment: From first look of the code given in the documentation it is clear that they are registering receiver with intent filters in oncreate and unregistering in on pause. Here they have register receiver at run time while same task you can do using registering receiver in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering Android Broadcast Receivers, this is something completely different from registering for push notifications.